# Remove duplicates from a sorted array - Leet Code 26

Tags: javascript

I'm working through a [LeetCode challenge 26. Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/):

> Given an integer array `nums` sorted in **non-decreasing** order, remove the duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only **once**. The **relative order** of the elements should be kept the **same**.
>
> Since it is impossible to change the length of the array in some languages, you must instead have the result be placed in the **first part** of the array `nums`. More formally, if there are `k` elements after removing the duplicates, then the first `k` elements of `nums` should hold the final result. It does not matter what you leave beyond the first `k` elements.
>
> Return `k` *after placing the final result in the first* `k` *slots of* `nums`.
>
> Do **not** allocate extra space for another array. You must do this by **modifying the input array [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)** with O(1) extra memory.

I'm not sure why my answer isn't being accepted. I believe I'm misinterpreting something simple.

#### The issue:

My solution only returns an empty array even though I appear to have the correct answer for the baseline test. Is there something that I'm overlooking on the implementation in regard to the rules of the challenge? `splice` edits elements in place.... so I thought that would be fine.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    const map = new Map();
    let count = 0;
    nums.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (map.get(item) === undefined){
            map.set(item, i);
        } else if (map.get(item) !== undefined) {
            nums.splice(i, 1);
            nums.push('_');
            count ++;
        }
    });
    return count;
};
```

I have also posted this as a question on [LeetCode's discussion section](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/discuss/1662384/Javascript-Solution-not-working).

Comment: Using a `Map` probably contradicts the challenge's instruction not to allocate another array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't splice out items from an array that you are iterating, as such iteration is based on an incrementing index, and the deletion will cause array values to *shift* to the left. So this double effect will make that you skip array values.

Moreover, you should avoid splicing all together as it represents a O(n) time complexity.

Also, the assignment says *"Do not allocate extra space ...  You must do this ... with O(1) extra memory."*, so collecting values in a `Map` is not what you are supposed to do. As the input array is sorted you really don't need this map either.

Instead use two indices: one that will be used for *reading* a value, and one where a value will be *written*. The first one will run ahead of the latter when there are duplicates.

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0) return 0;
    let k = 0;
    for (let value of nums) {
        if (value != nums[k]) {
            nums[++k] = value; 
        }
    }
    return k + 1;
};
```

Note that it is not necessary to modify the `length` of the array, as the code challenge says:

> ...the first `k` elements of `nums` should hold the final result.  It does not matter what you leave beyond the first `k` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the element with index `i` using `splice`, the array elements shift. The next iteration starts, you look at the element on index `i + 1`. But as the elements shifted, you miss the element that was on position `i + 1` and became the element on position `i` after the shift.

I assume that it would be wrong for me to post a correct answer as it is a challenge, other participants should solve it by themselves and not copy-paste an answer from here. So I'm just showing what do we get using current solution:

```js
const removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    const map = new Map();
    let count = 0;
    nums.forEach((item, i) => {
        if (map.get(item) === undefined){
            map.set(item, i);
        } else if (map.get(item) !== undefined) {
            nums.splice(i, 1);
            nums.push('_');
            count++;
        }
    });
    return count;
};

const nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]; // Input array
const expectedNums = [0,1,2,3,4]; // The expected answer with correct length

const k = removeDuplicates(nums); // Calls your implementation

console.log(nums.join(','))
console.log(expectedNums.join(','))
```